# Customize Windows Phone 8 Emulator startup state

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In developing a new Windows Phone app, we often install a custom certificate into the device to enable SSL proxying with Fiddler.

Is there any way to customize the starting device image so that we can start with the certificate installed instead of having to install the certificate every time the emulator launches?

I've found the xde.exe application where you can specify a device image and snapshot to use, but when launching the emulator from Visual Studio I can't find how to customize the launch parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article mentions how to take a snapshot of the Windows Phone 8 emulator which will save its state...

http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.ie/2013/01/saving-windows-phone-8-emulator-state.html

(*just to be clear, this does not apply to the Windows Phone 7 emulator*)

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Just a note for anybody following that blog post. Be sure to Reset the emulator _before_ taking the snapshot.  He mentions that in the blog post but mentions it _after_ saying to take the snapshot.  The first time I tried the steps I missed that and it didn't work.